# How can I take control over jumps `Ctrl-O` and `Ctrl-I` in Vimscript?

Tags: vim, vimscript

Is there any way I could use Vimscript to go through the list of jumps `Ctrl-O`, `Ctrl-I` and to pick the previous jump buffers/positions?

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Comment: As I have mentioned below, the problem is that `:execute "normal \<C-O>"` does not do what I want, because it jumps back only to 'buflisted' buffers and it omits any 'nobuflisted'. I'd be grateful if anyone could give me at least a hint in terms of any build-in function or way to be able to replay `Ctrl-0` or `Ctrl-I`  in Vim script so that it jumps through all buffers regardless whether listed or unlisted?

Answer (score 4):

You can execute the `Ctrl-O` and `Ctrl-I` commands within a script by using the `:execute` and `:normal` commands.

```
:execute "normal \<C-O>"
:execute "normal \<C-I>"
```

See

```
:help :normal
:help :execute
:help jump-motions
```

Comment: Will try it, seems very helpful. Thanks alot!

Comment: Actually, it's not working as I would like it bec `Ctrl-O` `Ctrl-I` work fine only for 'buflisted' but not for 'nobuflisted' buffers and not every 'nobuflisted' buffer i want to 'buflisted'. So, how would you then suggest me to find the `Ctrl-O` over unlisted buffers? Or perhaps is there is Vim build-in list or dict from where i could get the list of all jumps ?

Comment: I don't know how `Ctrl-O` and `Ctrl-I` are affected by the buffer states. I haven't thought too much about it. You can get a list of jumps by executing `:jumps`. If you want to capture that for use in a script, see `:help :redir`.

Comment: garyjon: thanks for your comments. I'm not sure if I am understanding of how i would use a :redir that dumps :jumps to a file? Please elaborate more on how could I in a Vim script "translate" a file with :redir of :jumps to something that could let me replay the `Ctrl-O`, `Ctrl-I`, `Ctrl-]`, and `Ctrl-T`. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know exactly what you're trying to achieve. I've so far been pointing you to you the pieces I think you might need to construct a solution. I think the discussion you started on the vim_use list will be more productive because there is not a straightforward answer to your question and discussion is encouraged on vim_use while it is discouraged here.

Comment: Note `"\<C-O>"` is a string literal for `ctrl-o`, not just something that `execute` interprets magically.